# Redirect specific traffic between two port on same device

Tags: debian, networking, tcp, bridge, socat

I have two running SIP applications on a Debian buster server, one app use port 1000 (a softphone) and another one using port 2000 (VoIP server like FreePBX).
both of them are on the same machine and OS.
I want to connect these two applications together on the same server via port bridging.
I used "SOCAT" but when SOCAT running the apps can not connect to the ports due to the port being opened by socat.

```
socat  TCP4-LISTEN:1000,reuseaddr TCP4-LISTEN:2000,reuseaddr
```

is there any other way to connect these two ports on localhost?
or can SOCAT listen to the port in another way like sniffing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: In which way do the applications *use*  the ports? Listen and wait for a connection? Initiate a connection? What protocol do the applications use to communicate?

Comment: The protocol is SIP, I want to run PJSIP as a client on the same machine that runs the VOIP server (FreePBX)

Comment: You could at least write in the question the exact socat command you're using in the attempt. Anyway SIP usually declares other streams (the voice itself etc.) in its commands and I'm not sure this kind of relaying will get these streams handled correctly.

Comment: Question Updated

Comment: Your `socat` command would *listen* on both ports and expect that both ends *connect* to the respective port. Is this right? I assume that your FreePBX acting as a SIP server will *listen on port 2000* and your SIP client implemented with PJSIP will *connect to port 1000*. In the latter case you would need simple port forwarding. But *why don't you configure/program one of FreePBX/PJSIP to use the matching port?* In the first case FreePBX seems to act as a client and I doubt that you can connect to SIP clients using `socat`. This is what SIP servers do.

Comment: you're right, but when you run both SIP client & server on same the machine, one of them open the port and make it busy, so another one can not connect the port and give an error.
So I need a way to forward the traffic to another port via 3rd party app to prevent this conflict.

Comment: I heared about some solutions like using IPTABLE routes but I did not succeed yet